# How to add files to your repository on github?

Tags: git, github, github-pages, github-for-windows

I'm new to Github, and I'm having issues using it. I created a repository, but I have no idea how to add files to the repository. How do I go about doing this?

Also, I have a PC if that helps.

Thanks:)

Comment: Clone your repository on your local machine. Add the files there. Commit your changes locally. Push your changes to the remote repository.

Comment: It's covered in this 15 minute tutorial: https://try.github.io

Comment: Well, are you trying to use git through the github site or command line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Git Bash shell on Windows. Then do the following to add files and commit files. The first command adds all files. If you just want to add one file, use $ git add .

$ git add .

$ git commit -m 'First commit'

https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-file-to-a-repository-from-the-command-line/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to your git directory...

Type **git status**

Git status shows the list of modified files...

The list has a green foreground color if it as been added but yet to be committed and a red foreground colour if it is yet to be added..

Type **git add filename**

To add a single file

And

Type **git add ***

To add all the edited files

Type **git commit - m "commit message"**

Type **git push origin develop**

To upload...

This link will help you JumpStart git 
http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/